# Symfony2 and Propel bundle: add additional filter to the Propel param converter

Tags: php, symfony, orm, propel

I am using a Propel parameter converter in one of my controller: (**Symfony 2.4.2 + Propel 1.7**)

```
 * @ParamConverter("center", converter="propel", class="MyCompany\Bundle\CoreBundle\Model\Center")
```

It's work well, but I'd like to add additional filters, typically a on a field `isVisible` (but the filter may be more complex), it is possible? In fact, what I'd like is to use a custom query function of my model and not the basic `findPk()` function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add option "repository_method" If you want to specify the repository method to use to find the entity

```
 * @ParamConverter("center", converter="propel", class="MyCompany\Bundle\CoreBundle\Model\Center", options={"repository_method" = "findByCustomQuery"})
```

Comment: Juts tester and unfortunately this option doesn't seem to be supported by Propel but only by Doctrine.

Comment: Oki, do you mean by propel 1.7 => propel 1.1.7, because version 1.7 doesn't exist

Comment: I think this can´t be done without modifying the code. Looking for the snippet.

Comment: Exactly, I just made a pull request
https://github.com/arffak/PropelBundle/commit/1c7e6ccdc643b566fad7fe8d07fd06b4b4960645

Comment: with this mofication you can use "query_method" option ==>  @ParamConverter("center", converter="propel", class="MyCompany\Bundle\CoreBundle\Model\Center", options={"query_method" = "findByCustomQuery"})

Comment: Excellent, I'll have a look next week see you.